# Por que o código gera lixo no início do vetor?

Tags: c, gcc

o seguinte código gera um resultado inesperado, no final do loop as primeiras posições do vetor estão com lixo armazenado, alguém sabe dizer porque isso está acontecendo, e onde está o erro?

OBS. O código tem o mesmo comportamento tanto em C como em C++ (compiladores gcc e g++)

Código:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>


    int V = 10;
    int E = 20;

    int main() {
        double sol[3*E + V];
        int ind[3*E + V];
        double val[3*E + V];
        double ub[3*E + V];
        double obj[3*E + V];
        char **varname;
        char vtype[V];
        int erro;


        varname = (char**) malloc((3*E+V)*sizeof(char**));

        for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i) {
            obj[i] = 0;
            vtype[i] = 'B';
            ub[i] = 1;
            varname[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
            sprintf(varname[i], "y_%i", i);
        }

        int k = 0;
        for (int i=V; i < (V+3*E); i+=3) {
            for(int j=0; j < 3; ++j) {
                obj[i+j] = 0;
                vtype[i+j] = 'B';
                ub[i+j] = 1;
                varname[i+j] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*)*15);
                sprintf(varname[i+j], "x_%i_%i_%i", 0, 0, j);
            }
            k++;
        }

        for (int i=0; i < (V+3*E); ++i) {
            printf(" obj[%d]: %.1f \t(%s), \t (%c) <= (%.1f)\n", i, obj[i], varname[i], vtype[i], ub[i]);
        }

        getchar();

    }
```

Saída:

```
    Success time: 0 memory: 2296 signal:0
     obj[0]: 156842099844.5     (y_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[1]: 156842099844.5     (y_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[2]: 156842099844.5     (y_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[3]: 156842099844.5     (y_3),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[4]: 156842099844.5     (y_4),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[5]: 156842099844.5     (y_5),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[6]: 0.0    (y_6),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[7]: 0.0    (y_7),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[8]: 0.0    (y_8),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[9]: 0.0    (y_9),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[10]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[11]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[12]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[13]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[14]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[15]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[16]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[17]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[18]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[19]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[20]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[21]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[22]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[23]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[24]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[25]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[26]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[27]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[28]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[29]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[30]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[31]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[32]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[33]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[34]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[35]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[36]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[37]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[38]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[39]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[40]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[41]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[42]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[43]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[44]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[45]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[46]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[47]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[48]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[49]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[50]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[51]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[52]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[53]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[54]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[55]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[56]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[57]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[58]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[59]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[60]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[61]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[62]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[63]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[64]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[65]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[66]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[67]: 0.0   (x_0_0_0),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[68]: 0.0   (x_0_0_1),   (B) <= (1.0)
     obj[69]: 0.0   (x_0_0_2),   (B) <= (1.0)
```

Abraços!

Answer (score 2):

Seu array `vtype` tem apenas tamanho 10, mas você escreve nele como se ele tivesse o mesmo tamanho dos outros. Da forma como as variáveis locais são estruturadas, você acaba escrevendo em cima da memória dos outros arrays. Neste caso você está escrevendo por cima do array `obj`, o que acaba gerando o lixo que você observou.

Comment: Putz! Isso mesmo! Muito obrigado!